# DIV not visible in Table cell when height set to 100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a red rectangle icon followed by some text within a HTML Table cell and I am getting very strange behavior here. I am using just a DIV to draw the red rectangle as shown in the example here. I want the height of rectangle to be the height of the cell so I set the height: 100%

https://jsfiddle.net/pm43k26w/1/

```
<table border="1">
    <td>
        <div style="width:10px;height:100%;background:red;display:inline-block"></div>
        Height in percentage
    </td>
    <td>
        <div style="width:10px;height:10px;background:red;display:inline-block"></div>
        Fixed Height
    </td>    
</table>
```

The solution kind of works in Chrome but not in FireFox. FireFox just shows a blank space. It appears it does not like it when I set the height to 100% Can anyone explain why? What's the best way to accomplish this if DIV isn't the right way to go for the rectangle?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to give vertical-align to your rectangle? It worked for me by giving it vertical-align: top

Comment: @lecya That doesn't work in firefox (see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hevhfye/))

Answer (score 3):

Firefox needs content in the div. The following modification will do. The numerical entity is Unicode's 'zero width space character'. A non-breaking space ( `&nbsp;`) will do as well, of course.

```
<div style="width:10px;height:100%;background:red;display:inline-block">&#8203;</div>
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1en1qcr/).

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly, you need to understand the problem here. `CSS` Properties such as height are "Computed"**. In this particular case, the computed height of the first div (let's call it *unseenForce*, shall we?) is 0 while its cousin, aptly named **seenForce** is 10px. See this below :

http://jsfiddle.net/gvo4kf41/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Info').html('The computed height of the unseenForce is ' + $('#unseenForce').height() + 'px <br />');
  $('.Info').append(document.createTextNode('The computed height of the seenForce is '+ $('#seenForce').height() + 'px'));
});
```

```css
.Info {
  color: red;
  margin-top : 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <td>
        <div id="unseenForce" style="width:10px;height:100%;background:red;display:inline-block"></div>
        Height in percentage
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="seenForce" style="width:10px;height:10px;background:red;display:inline-block"></div>
        Fixed Height
    </td>    
</table>

<div class="Info">
  
</div>
```

*This is because none of the ancestors of the `unseenForce` have a specific height to them. Hence, Firefox is unable to attach a `height` to it.*

What you need to do it force the **Computed value** of height to be greater that 0. There are many ways to do it and all the answers here show you different ways of doing it. Choose the one which suits your needs.

Here's the way I would do it. Just add height to the row (`<td>`).

```css
table td {
    height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <td>
        <div id="unseenForce" style="width:10px;height:100%;background:red;display:inline-block"></div>
        Height in percentage
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="seenForce" style="width:10px;height:100%;background:red;display:inline-block"></div>
        Fixed Height
    </td>    
</table>

<div class="Info">
  
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the parent element.

```
<td style="height:20px">
```

That should help with the Firefox problem.

**Edit:** JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/prove64m/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you forgot the `<tr>` tag.
So this should be the correct HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <div></div> first text
       </td>
       <td>
          <div></div> second text
       </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then the CSS part:

```
table {
    border:1px solid;
}
td {
    height:40px;
}
div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:10px;
    height:100%;
    background:red
}
```

Pay attention that the height is ALWAYS evaluated, so, if there isn't any explicitily set, there is nothing "to compute"; we did this here:

```
td {
    height:40px;
}
```

Other important thing; i guess you would like to control the position of the text after the `<div>` element; this is possible with online-block elements in this way:

```
div {
    ...
    vertical-align:bottom;
    ...
}
```

Other possible values are: middle, top,...

here the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pm43k26w/5/

Comment: 'There is nothing to compute': Well, Chrome does compute a height, and imho in a most sensible way. The height of the table cell can be established by its textual content which in turn can provide a reference measure to the table cell's `div` child. Do the W3C standards address this issue ?